# Beego API Document swagger returns 404

Tags: swagger, beego

I am following this [blog](http://beego.me/blog/beego_api) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7RziV_Sn-g) to do the API demo, when I visit

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger I can see the link

/swagger-1/
```

but when I click it, It returns 404. Anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug.

**Generally you can see the Beego auto generated  swagger document by visiting**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger/swagger-1/
```

---

The issue is if you visited from

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger
```

after clicking the link it will go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger-1/
```

which will return 404.

However if you visited from

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger/
```

after clicking the link it will go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger/swagger-1/
```

which will give you the documents you want.

Answer (score 2):

Doownload this link  https://github.com/beego/swagger and put it to your project. Then,go http://localhost:8080/swagger/